# How to pass the value of the variable from get to post MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Get method:

```
public ActionResult Add(string id)
{}
```

I want to read the value of the variable "id" in the method of post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(List<class_of_data> clazz)
{}
```

Comment: I assume you're somehow calling the Add(List<class_of_data> clazz) from the Add(string id) ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Add(string id)
{
    ViewBag.ModelId = id;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(List <class_of_data> classList, string id)
{
// you can set int id if you need it as an number since MVC will convert it.
// Also keep in mind that class in a reserved keyword. Changed it to classList 
// DO SOME STUFF
}
```

And the View should be something like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
// some code
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='@ViewBag.ModelId' />
// some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are submit a form and wish to have lose model binding or there is no model binding, then this solution might be useful for you.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FormSubmit(FormCollection form)
    {
        string id= form["id"].ToString();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

And your view should look something like this

```
<input type="textbox" name="id" />
<input type="submit" Value="Submit Form" />
```

Hope this solution works for you.